# How to prevent controller endpoints only available for a certain lifecycle environment in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot

```
Delete an article using DELETE /articles/:id 
Delete all articles using DELETE /articles/
```

How can I make deletion support **available** only in dev environment and prevent it for test, staging, production environments in spring boot

Answer (score 2):

First thing that comes to my mind would be adding a `DeletionController` which is created either based on a property or, in your case, on the active profile.
Something like:

```java
@Profile("dev")
@RestController
public class DeletionController {

   @DeleteMapping("articles")
   public void deleteAll() {
   //delete all articles
   }

   @DeleteMapping("articles/{id}")
   public void delete(@PathVariable Integer id) {
   //delete article for given id
   }
}
```

Doing so Spring will only instantiate the `DeletionController` when the `dev` profile is active making the related endpoints available only in that case. You also have the possibility to have it active/inactive with more complex conditions like `@Profile("dev & staging")` or `@Profile("dev & !production")`. You can control the active profiles in your property file with the property `spring.profiles.active`.

The property approach would be using, instead of `@Profile`, the annotation `@ConditionalOnProperty` properly configured.